# Qtip tooltip doesn't work

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

Halo! I'm new to JQuery and I'm trying to make simple tooltip with QTip. I'm sure that I already follow the steps right but the tooltip doesn't seem working. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select-here').qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'tooltip here',
            show: 'mouseover',
            hide: 'mouseout'
        },       
        style: {
            width: 400,
            height: 400
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And in the body i wrote this

```
<div class="select-here">Text text text</div>
```

Did I miss something? Anyone can help me with this? 
Thank you

Comment: did you add its CSS and also did you checked its referencing correctly with images?

Comment: what sort of output do you get in the browser console?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan yes I already added css and it references to the class correctly

Comment: @gaoshan88 it says "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'". Could it be the problem?

Comment: I found what's wrong, turns out i put the qtip before i put jquery reference so it didn't recognize the method. Thank you @gaoshan88 for making me check the console!

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Tdh4a/

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/basic

I reckon `show and hide` are seperate attribute instead of child of content: check here in documentation: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#content

Also you will notice in the qTip link that they are promoting qTip2 instead of qTip as its Obsolete. Rest demo should help your cause. `B-)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".select-here").qtip({
        content: {
            text: "HULK Me HULK HULK",
            title: {
                text: "Title",
                button: true
            }
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            event: 'unfocus'
        },
        position: {
            target: 'mouse',
            viewport: $(window),
            adjust: {
                method: 'flip shift',
                mouse: false
            }
        },
        style: {
            tip: false,
            widget: false
        }
    });


});​
```